# How to unselect all rows from Material-UI's <Table> in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI's `<Table/>` with ReactJS. Currently I have the `<Table/>` select all checkbox working, and it keeps track of which row has been clicked on via `onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection}`. But once I uncheck the select all checkbox, it unchecks all the rows' checkboxes except the very last row.

How can I get it so that unchecking the select all checkbox will actually unselect *all* rows' checkboxes?

Here is the code:

```
export default class TestTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      clickedRowIds: [],
    }

    this.handleRowSelection = this.handleRowSelection.bind(this);
  }

  handleRowSelection(rowIds) {
    let rowsAll = []

    if (rowIds === 'all') { //get all the id's from data
      this.state.rows.map((row, index) => {rowsAll.push(index)})
    } else {
      this.setState({
        clickedRowIds: rowIds
      })
    }
  }

  render(){

    return(

      <div>
        <Table
          multiSelectable={true}
          onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection}
        >
          <TableHeader
            displaySelectAll={true}
            enableSelectAll={true}
          >
              ...
              //rows is just an array of objects, and each row is represented by one object in that array
              {
              this.state.rows.map((row, index) => { return(<TableRow selected={this.state.clickRowIds.indexOf(rowIndex) !== -1}/> })
              }
          </TableHeader>
        </Table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo here - it should be "!==" not "!--"

```
this.state.clickRowIds.indexOf(rowIndex) !-- -1
```

Comment: It was `!==` but just copied it in incorrectly. Could something else be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no native way to do this, I have a workaround:

1. ref TableBody
2. clear state.selectedRows of TableBody

Example:

ref

```
<TableBody deselectOnClickaway={false} ref={tableBody => this.tableBody = tableBody}>
```

Clear selection

```
this.tableBody.setState({ selectedRows: [] });
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solved the exact same problem.
Your render method should return this:

```
<div>
    <Table
      selectable={true}
      multiSelectable={true}
      onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection}
    >
      <TableHeader
        displaySelectAll={true}
        enableSelectAll={true}
      >
      </TableHeader>

      <TableBody 
        displayRowCheckbox={true} 
        displaySelectAll={true} 
        deselectOnClickaway={false}
      >
          ...
      </TableBody>


    </Table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer solves the question being asked?

Comment: I had the same problem until I added that table configuration.

Comment: I think all that is needed is the `deselectOnClickaway={false}`. Having that one set to `true` would toggle the "select all" checkbox one too many times.